# sifr 3 - at my wits' end trying to get the text blocks not to wrap

Tags: sifr

Looking forward to any help/comments on any aspect of this, but the main question is about sIFR text wrapping, and how to disallow it. This was supposed to be a simple html-izing job (ha ha ha)

[Check out here](http://esdaile-ryus.com/clientarea/fluidtrade/newhtml/)

So I've housed the nav and the content clip boxes in tables, which I know you purists might disdain, but it seemed the easiest/most consistent way... please forgive.

The problem is the sIFR - I can't get one of the nav items ("Exchange Technologies") to behave; it keeps wrapping. Meanwhile, the sIFR headlines in the little content boxes have become unruly and are trying to escape.

I've clogged up the CSS trying to fix it in various elements -- I would be so eternally grateful if a sIFR expert would check it out and see if there are any suggestions on making the sIFR heads work.

Note that I do not need any padding on the bottom of the sIFR elements because the headlines are rendered in all caps.

If it would help I could send along the image of what the designer was looking for.

Comment: It looks like fitExactly:true might help with some of the weird behavior, but I'm not sure where that parameter goes -- in the sifr.js file, or in the html file?

Answer (score 1):

The `forceSingleLine` parameter for `sIFR.replace()` is the easiest way to resolve this. The problem usually arises when the Flash text is wider than the HTML text, and the elements being replaced are exactly the width of the HTML text. In this case the sIFR text won't fit in the allowed space without wrapping.

Another solution is to use `letter-spacing` through `.sIFR-active .myNavItemToBeReplaced` CSS rules, to make the HTML text wider so the Flash text does fit without wrapping.